# Attempt to de-reference a null object - Apex Code error

Tags: apex

I am trying to do some custom functionality with the Case object but facing "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error. Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Below goes my VF page code:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Case" extensions="detailsController" showHeader="False" sidebar="False">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please fill in the below details">
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_fname__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_lname__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_alias__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_email__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_CommunityNickname__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_role__c}" required="True"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_license__c}" required="True"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_profile__c}" required="True"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!c.user_EmailEncodingKey__c}" required="True"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <center>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveRec}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Reset All" action="{!resetAll}" immediate="True"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel & Back to Previous" action="{!returnBack}" immediate="true"/>
        </center>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the details controller is as below:

```
public with sharing class detailsController {    
    public Case c{get;set;}

    public detailsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        Case c = new Case();
    }

    //Method to reset all the fields
    Public PageReference resetAll(){
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/User_Detail_Page');
            pageRef.setredirect(true);
            return pageRef ;        
    }

    //Method to go back to the earlier page
    Public PageReference returnBack(){
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CloneThisUser');
            pageRef.setredirect(true);
            return pageRef ;        
    }


    //Method to set the default values required for saving the records
    public void setDefault(){
       c.Origin = 'Web';
       c.user_isActive__c = True;
       c.user_app__c = True;
       c.Subject = 'New User Creation Request';
    }

    //Method to save the inserted values
    public void saveRec(){
        setDefault();
        insert c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please only assign the memory to the variable in constructor, not declare it again. Change the constructor code as given below:

```
public detailsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   c = new Case();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `controller.getRecord()`?